# Multiple filters Python Data.frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm pretty new to python. I'm trying to filter rows in a data.frame as I do in R.

```
sub_df = df[df[main_id]==3]
```

works, but

```
df[df[main_id] in [3,7]]
```

gives me error

> "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous"

Can you please suggest me a correct syntax to write similar selections?

Comment: Can you include the original dataframe? Output of `print(df.head())`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use pandas [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) function. This would look like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': ['a', 'b', 'f']})
df[df['A'].isin([2, 3])]
```

giving:

```
   A  B
1  2  b
2  3  f
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was resolutive

Answer (score 1):

```
df[df[main_id].apply(lambda x: x in [3, 7])]
```

Answer (score 1):

yet another solution:

```
In [60]: df = pd.DataFrame({'main_id': [0,1, 2, 3], 'x': list('ABCD')})

In [61]: df
Out[61]:
   main_id  x
0        0  A
1        1  B
2        2  C
3        3  D

In [62]: df.query("main_id in [0,3]")
Out[62]:
   main_id  x
0        0  A
3        3  D
```